# Not able to access Internal static Classes in Faking framework in MSTEST VS 2013

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, mstest, microsoft-fakes

I want to mock Internal static classes of main project into Test project. I am using Faking framework.
I have tried these Attributes in Main project where actual static class resides.

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("ReportGeneratorUnitTestProject")]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("ReportGeneratorUnitTestProject.Fakes")]
```

Where `ReportGeneratorUnitTestProject` is my Test project. Above attribute is defined in main project whose dll is being used in the Test project.

Please help and advice.

Screen Shot of project structure.
[image]

Comment: I think there are a couple issues here. First and foremost is that you aren't making the internals visible to the generator, just the generated project. I don't think there's any way to do this. Internals are, from a testing standpoint, implementation details, and so many people would suggest not testing them at all. There certainly isn't a *nice* way of doing it.

Comment: According to this, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh708916.aspx#BKMK_Internal_types, that looks right.  Any way to see your solution structure?